# Change default views zend framework behaviour

Tags: php, zend-framework

I just found out that my actions can use the same view just, just changing some parameters.

So, as  */controller/* loads *'path/to/scripts/controller/**index.phtml**'*, I want *controller/action1* to load also *'path/to/scripts/controller/**index.phtml**'* instead of loading *'path/to/scripts/controller/**action1.phtml**'*, as it does by default. Which is the cleanest way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in your **action1** of the same controller:

```
$this->_helper->viewRenderer('index');
```